# Find string in array of strings where some element not equal zero

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array of strings. How can I find elements not equal zero and print these strings? How can I do it properly?

This is what I want to see:

```
Port        Align-Err     FCS-Err    Xmit-Err     Rcv-Err  UnderSize  OutDiscards "
Gi0/16              0         116           0         116          0           56
Gi0/3               0           0           23          0          0       315887
Po1                 0      232464           0      232464          0     21331230
```

My array:

```
array = [
        "Port        Align-Err     FCS-Err    Xmit-Err     Rcv-Err  UnderSize  OutDiscards ", 
        "Gi0/1               0           0           0           0          0       212086 ", 
        "Gi0/2               0           0           0           0          0       184832 ", 
        "Gi0/3               0           0           23          0          0       315887 ", 
        "Gi0/4               0           0           0           0          0       253439 ", 
        "Gi0/5               0           0           0           0          0       135034 ", 
        "Gi0/6               0           0           0           0          0       132617 ", 
        "Gi0/7               0           0           0           0          0         5816 ", 
        "Gi0/8               0           0           0           0          0        12266 ", 
        "Gi0/9               0           0           0           0          0       573217 ", 
        "Gi0/10              0           0           0           0          0       844880 ", 
        "Gi0/11              0           0           0           0          0       264766 ", 
        "Gi0/12              0           0           0           0          0       197496 ", 
        "Gi0/13              0           0           0           0          0            0 ", 
        "Gi0/14              0           0           0           0          0       372725 ", 
        "Gi0/15              0           0           0           0          0     14260434 ", 
        "Gi0/16              0         116           0         116          0           56 ", 
        "Gi0/17              0           0           0           0          0      6905901 ", 
        "Gi0/18              0           0           0           0          0       333387 ", 
        "Po1                 0      232464           0      232464          0     21331230 ", 
]
```

Comment: Do you want that closing double-quote at the end of the first line of output? Is that output to be printed or returned in some kind of data structure? Which part of this overall problem is your difficulty: splitting your strings into their component parts, filtering out the rows of zeros, or aligning your filtered array into columns? What is the basis of sorting the rows in your output? (The output order differs from the input order.) Please give more context to your problem, including some of your attempts to solve it.

Comment: No, I don't want closing double-quotes, it's my mistake. 
I have to determine which Gi0/1 - Gi0/16 have some errors. This is my goal.

The output maybe look different, it's not matter.
In my example, Gi0/16, Gi0/3 and Po1 have errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Below are the two methods which I can suggest:

### 1. Simple for loop, here I have ignored first and last element: (I guess this is what you need)

```
for i in array:
    if any(x!="0" for x in i.split()[1:-1]): # here 1:-1 are the range where we are checking the values, you can edit it as per your need
        print (i)
```

### 2. Same using list comprehension

```
print ([i for i in array if any(x!="0" for x in i.split()[1:-1])])
```

### Output:

```
Port        Align-Err     FCS-Err    Xmit-Err     Rcv-Err  UnderSize  OutDiscards 
Gi0/3               0           0           23          0          0       315887 
Gi0/16              0         116           0         116          0           56 
Po1                 0      232464           0      232464          0     21331230
```

### Added function way of doing it as requested:

```
def getErrorList(array):
    return [i for i in array if any(x!="0" for x in i.split()[1:-2])] #check the range [1:-2] carefully. Use it as per your need.

print (getErrorList(array)) #take it in a variable for further processing
```

Comment: how can I use this code in function? 
def some_name(array):
  you code here...
return x

Comment: @VladimirFomin: I have added a new section in the answer. I hope this answer is an acceptable one. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ll= [ x.split() for x in array]
df = pd.DataFrame(ll)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))
df[['Align-Err', 'FCS-Err', 'Xmit-Err', 'Rcv-Err', 'UnderSize', 'OutDiscards']] = df[['Align-Err', 'FCS-Err', 'Xmit-Err', 'Rcv-Err', 'UnderSize', 'OutDiscards']].astype(int)
```

I do not get the part in which you want to find elements not equal 0. What elements? what column? you have zero in each row.

```
df = df[df != 0].dropna()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# your code goes here
array = [
        'Port        Align-Err     FCS-Err    Xmit-Err     Rcv-Err  UnderSize  OutDiscards ', 
        'Gi0/1               0           0           0           0          0       212086 ', 
        'Gi0/2               0           0           0           0          0       184832 ', 
        'Gi0/3               0           0           23          0          0       315887 ', 
        'Gi0/4               0           0           0           0          0       253439 ', 
        'Gi0/5               0           0           0           0          0       135034 ', 
        'Gi0/6               0           0           0           0          0       132617 ', 
        'Gi0/7               0           0           0           0          0         5816 ', 
        'Gi0/8               0           0           0           0          0        12266 ', 
        'Gi0/9               0           0           0           0          0       573217 ', 
        'Gi0/10              0           0           0           0          0       844880 ', 
        'Gi0/11              0           0           0           0          0       264766 ', 
        'Gi0/12              0           0           0           0          0       197496 ', 
        'Gi0/13              0           0           0           0          0            0 ', 
        'Gi0/14              0           0           0           0          0       372725 ', 
        'Gi0/15              0           0           0           0          0     14260434 ', 
        'Gi0/16              0         116           0         116          0           56 ', 
        'Gi0/17              0           0           0           0          0      6905901 ', 
        'Gi0/18              0           0           0           0          0       333387 ', 
        'Po1                 0      232464           0      232464          0     21331230 ', 
]

# Splits at space 
for row in array:
    rowData = row.split()
    if(rowData[2] != '0'):
        print(row)
```

which yields

```
Port        Align-Err     FCS-Err    Xmit-Err     Rcv-Err  UnderSize  OutDiscards   
Gi0/16              0         116           0         116          0           56   
Po1                 0      232464           0      232464          0     21331230
```

Comment: Your code leaves out the "Gi0/3" line. You need to test more than just column 2.

Comment: The precise logical combination of which variables should not be 0 in order to print a row is essentially a boolean satisfiability problem. I am not going to attempt to randomly guess these parameters. I have given the original poster a good basis to get started from.

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your question, isn't clear.

I assume that you want values with one or more 'something-Err' column not equal to zero

you can do something like:

```
def f(arr):
    yield arr[0] # labels
    for elem in arr[1:]:
        _, align_err, fcs_err, xmit_err, rcv_err, *_ = elem.split()
        if any(map(lambda s: int(s) != 0, (align_err, fcs_err, xmit_err, rcv_err))):
            yield elem
```

Then use it just like this:

```
>>> for elem in f(array):
...     print(elem)
...
Port        Align-Err     FCS-Err    Xmit-Err     Rcv-Err  UnderSize  OutDiscards
Gi0/3               0           0           23          0          0       315887
Gi0/16              0         116           0         116          0           56
Po1                 0      232464           0      232464          0     21331230
```